# Magento products in wishlist replaced

Tags: magento

I am trying to insert products in wish-list programmatically it works fine
for some products,but for some products it replaced the last wishlist product

I am referring this 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/19678/how-do-i-add-to-wishlist-programatically

Please any help on this would be really helpful.

Comment: Please read [ask]. You need to show us your code and provide enough information that you don't need to link off-site.

Comment: I am using this code: $wishlist =Mage::getModel('wishlist/wishlist')->loadByCustomer($customerId, true);
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);

$buyRequest = new Varien_Object(array()); // any possible options that are configurable and you want to save with the product

$result = $wishlist->addNewItem($product, $buyRequest);
$wishlist->save();

Comment: Please don't post your code as a comment. Edit your question. And provide enough information to support your code. What products work? What don't? etc.

Comment: @Enigmativity do you mean you want to create something that will automatically add things to your basket, based on the items you have?